# Slow copy speeds from SD card to SSD?

Tags: file-copy

I have a Debian (with kernel 5.10.110 #178) on aarch64 architecture.

I'm trying to copy an SD card (SanDisk Extreme, microSD XC UHS-I V30, 64GB) to an SSD (Intel Optane, 16GB).

Based on the [Sandisk](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/memory-cards/sandisk-extreme-uhs-i-microsd#SDSQXAH-064G-GN6MA)'s specification page, this SD card has 170MBps sequential reading capability, and the [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/97544/intel-optane-memory-series-16gb-m-2-80mm-pcie-3-0-20nm-3d-xpoint/specifications.html) SSD has 145MBps sequential write speeds.

These are obviously maximum values, but when I try copying from SD to SSD, I got *much* lower speeds:

```
rsync -ah --progress src/* dst
sending incremental file list
File_1.MP4
        256.88M 100%   49.75MB/s    0:00:04 (xfr#1, to-chk=1/2)
File_2.MP4
          1.27G 100%   47.60MB/s    0:00:25 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/2)
```

As you can see it barely reaches 50MBps which is roughly the third of the Intel SSD's write capabilities.

SD card reader is UHS-I capable. CPU is *Rockchip RK3568B2*, clocked at 2GHz with 4x Cortex-A55.

During this filecopy, the CPU is not (really) loaded:

[image]

Can I make this transfer faster?

### Update

- When I copy from SD to internal eMMC, I got ~110MBps transfer speeds.
- Intel Optane NVMe SSD is attached to an M2 port which has only PCIe2.1 x1 capability (Max 500MBps).
- Copying from internal eMMC to SSD I got the same ~50MBps transfer rates.
- SD/MMC Interface: Compatible with SD3.0, MMC ver4.51 (Data bus width is 4bits)

Comment: What is your »SD card reader«? A dedicated MMC port of the CPU? 4 bits? Which clock speed? DMA? Cache policy of the RAM area?

Comment: I think the slowness is caused by the SSD, please see my update.